# Looping through array text not responding

Tags: javascript

```js
document.getElementById("changeText").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var text = ["This", "is", "a", "secret", "message"];
  for (var counter=0; counter < text.length-1; counter++) {
  document.getElementById("heading").innerText = text[counter];

  }
});
```

```html
<h1 id="heading">This heading will change</h1>
<button id="changeText">change text</button>
```

You may or may not be able to tell but I am just starting out in Javascript and am practicing a few concepts.

The idea behind this is, when the user clicks on the button, it loops through the array and replaces the h1 inner text with each element of the array. However, when I click on the button, the only element that replaces the inner HTML is text[3] of the array, which of course is "secret".

Why is this happening? Please bare in mind I am new to Javascript and am still learning. As far as I can see, I have declared the counter to start at 0, and conditioned it to stop once it reaches the length of the array - 1, and I have incremented it by one each time. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Please help.

Comment: You're actually replacing the text 4 times, once with `text[0]` then once with `text[1]` then once with `text[2]` etc..  You only see the result of the last replace.

Comment: Instead of loop you may use **document.getElementById("heading").textContent = text.join(' ');**

Comment: Are you wanting it to say "This" and then "is" and then "a"... or are you wanting it to just say "This is a secret message"?

Comment: Hi Matt! Yes, I am looking for it to loop through each array element upon every click. So when the user first clicks on the button, the first element to replace the h1 is "this", and then clicks on it again, it is replaced by "is", and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

There are two separate issues in that code:

1. You're stopping your loop too early. It should be `< text.length` or `<= text.length - 1` but not `< text.length - 1`.
2. You're not giving the browser a chance to redraw the element before updating its text on the next pass. You can use `setTimeout` to do that.

Here's an example handling both, see `***` comments:

```js
// *** A function we use to update the text
function updateText(el, thisText) {
  el.textContent = thisText;
}

document.getElementById("changeText").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var text = ["This", "is", "a", "secret", "message"];
  // *** Look up the element *once*
  var el = document.getElementById("heading");
  // *** Use "< text.length"
  for (var counter=0; counter < text.length; counter++) {
    // *** Schedule a timed callback
    setTimeout(
      updateText,       // *** The function to call
      counter * 500,    // *** Delay before calling, each is 500ms later than previous
      el, text[counter] // *** Arguments for the timer to pass the function
    );
  }
});
```

```html
<h1 id="heading">This heading will change</h1>

<button id="changeText">change text</button>
```

There are other changes above as well:

- `textContent` rather than `innerText`. If supporting older IE, you may need to feature-detect to see which to use. Or for your messages, you can get away with setting `innerHTML` instead.
- Note avoiding creating a function in the loop, since we just need one.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues here:

1) In your for loop defintion, you are checking if counter is less than `text.length-1` instead of `text.length`, which means that the loop is stopping one element shy of the end of the array.

2) Inside the for loop, you are replacing the entire heading, instead of appending to it. So the heading gets set to each individual word, one at a time, but it runs so fast that you only see the last iteration of this. Change the line inside the for loop to this:

```
document.getElementById("heading").innerText = document.getElementById("heading").innerText + text[counter];
```

This can also be shortened to this cleaner form:

```
document.getElementById("heading").innerText += text[counter];
```